# Debug Django code in Docker

Tags: django, debugging, docker

I want to debug my Django code running through docker container. Is it possible with PDB, PYCHARM debugger or with another technique?

Answer (score 3):

It was made possible in pycharm pro 2017.1 and up.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/docker.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse its possible, with any remote debugger (quick Google search - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/remote-pdb) you just need to take care of networking and connect to the debugger's port (e.g. `docker run -p ...`)